# Argument error when compiling .exe from Python using PyInstaller

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write a screen recorder program in python. My code runs normally in the compiler. But when I convert it to .exe, it raises this error:

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (415) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): project.avi in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

I used pyinstaller to convert to .exe.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox as msj
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from PIL import ImageGrab
import os
import time

import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

recording=False
i = 0
size = 100, 100

mainWindow=Tk()
mainWindow.title("ScreenRecorder")
mainWindow.geometry("200x200")

scriptDirectory = (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

def convert(imageCount):
    img_array = []
    for ip in range(1,imageCount):
        x="snap"+str(ip)+".jpg"
        for filename in glob.glob(x):
            img = cv2.imread(filename)
            height, width, layers = img.shape
            size = (width,height)
            img_array.append(img)

    out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 9, size)

    for iz in range(len(img_array)):
        out.write(img_array[iz])

    out.release()

    for a in range(1,imageCount+1):
        os.remove("snap"+str(a)+".jpg")

def record():
    global i
    print(recording)
    if(recording==True):
        i+=1
        fileName= ("snap"+str(i))
        #time.sleep(0.00005)
        image = ImageGrab.grab()
        name=fileName+".jpg"
        image.save(name,'JPEG')

        imgX = (Image.open("snap"+str(i)+".jpg"))
        imgX= imgX.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        imgX=ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgX)

    mainWindow.after(1, record)

def startButton():
    global recording
    print("ehe")
    recording=True
    record()

def stopButton():
    global recording
    recording=False
    record()
    convert(i)


startButton=Button(text="Start",command=startButton)
startButton.pack()
stopButton=Button(text="Stop",command=stopButton)
stopButton.pack()

mainWindow.after(1, record)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just advise you to use another method, i think it's more simple, try to use 'auto py to exe'.This is a module that can be installed from the net or from the pip installer.
see from [here](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/).This the only way that i use for my codes.
Secondly, iknow that if the program is not opened using the format of .py will never be opened at .exe
hope i helped you.

Comment: auto-py-to-exe is using PyInstaller as well.